# Get text/html response from johnculviner/jquery.fileDownload

Tags: jquery, download

How can I get text/html response from my johnculviner/jquery.fileDownload request?

This is my code that works great when every things is ok in backend:

```
var c = new Date().getTime();
params.cookieName = c;
var op = {
    cookieName: c.toString(),
    cookiePath: '/' + context + '/',
    preparingMessageHtml: messageSuccess,
    failMessageHtml: messageError,
    data: params,
    successCallback: function(url) {
        // ????? Can I get my response Here?????
        if (functionSuccess) {
            functionSuccess();
        }
    },
    failCallback: function(responseHtml, url) {
        if (responseHtml) {
        //Error code...
        };
    }
};
$.fileDownload(url, op);
```

Can I get my text response in successCallback function? Where can I?

My Response Header from Java backend contains this: `Content-Type:text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1`
My response is: `[{"error":"Error Message"}]`

Answer (score 0):

This is the full extent of what you have access to. This isn't AJAX that is being used (AJAX does not universally support initiating a file download). You don't have access to headers or anything other than cookies if the response comes back successfully (file download started). If you want to communicate something to the client with a successfully initiated file download use a cookie (which is how the plugin works to begin with)

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on("click", "a.fileDownloadCustomRichExperience", function () {

        var $preparingFileModal = $("#preparing-file-modal");

        $preparingFileModal.dialog({ modal: true });

        $.fileDownload($(this).prop('href'), {
            successCallback: function (url) {

                $preparingFileModal.dialog('close');
            },
            failCallback: function (responseHtml, url) {

                $preparingFileModal.dialog('close');
                $("#error-modal").dialog({ modal: true });
            }
        });
        return false; //this is critical to stop the click event which will trigger a normal file download!
    });
});
```